# Map all existing aws security groups in terraform

Tags: loops, terraform

I would like to source existing aws security group information allowing for them to be referenced by name rather than id.

I can reference a single existing instance using:

```
data "aws_security_groups" "single" {
  filter {
    name   = "group-name"
    values = ["Foo-all"]
  }
}

output "singlename" {
  value = "${data.aws_security_groups.single.ids[0]}"
}
```

This isn't ideal, as I would need to enter all the security group ids as their own block.

I can get all of the attributes for all of the security groups printed using:

```
data "aws_security_groups" "sgroups" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = ["${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"]
  }
}

data "aws_security_group" "instances" {
  count = length(data.aws_security_groups.sgroups.ids)
  id = data.aws_security_groups.test.ids[count.index]
}

output "groupinfo" {
  value = "${data.aws_security_group.instances}"
}
```

This isn't useful, to me, as I want a Name = id mapping.

What I'm hoping to do is define all of the existing security groups as a map so I could do something like the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "fooTest" {
  ami           = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  subnet_id = "${var.subnets["Foo-net"]}"
  key_name = "Fookey"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ 
    "${var.existingsgs["Foo-all"]}",
  ]
}
```

Can this be done? Or is there a better way of achieving name based security group references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can output a map, you should be able to output a list of sec group id's using a data source like you've done with your example code. Take that a step further by filtering the data source to grab resources that are tagged with specific labels. Then just reference the data resource inside your aws_instance resource block.

Example by request:

To read existing vpc and security groups use a data source. Select the desired target by filtering on specific tags that are applied to the vpc and security groups.

```
data "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  tags = {
    Project     = "my_vpc"
    Environment = "qa"
  }
}

data "aws_security_group" "my_sg" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"

  tags = {
    Name        = "my_sg"
    Environment = "qa"
  }
}
```

When you create your resource you can reference the data sources you have grabbed. Remember data sources are read first to make them available to use when creating additional resources.

```
resource "aws_instance" "fooTest" {
  ami           = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  subnet_id = "${var.subnets["Foo-net"]}"
  key_name = "Fookey"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${data.aws_security_group.my_sg.ids}"]
}
```

You can also do the same thing with subnets, nearly anything that exists in AWS can be read into a data source block for referencing when creating additional resources.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html

Comment: Could you post some example code for your solution?

Comment: There ya go! That should get you close.